# How to disable loopback with alsamixer?

Tags: audio, alsamixer

A column "loopback" appeared on my alsamixer panel, so that I don't have any sound even when properly set. Which module should be removed

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the mixer settings, so removing modules won't help.

In `alsamixer`, use left and right arrows to move the red highlight to `Loopback`, then up and down arrows to enable and disable it.

If this doesn't work for some reason, you can also use `amixer` to display and set the mixer controls from the command line. Make sure to select the right card with `-c`. Details in `man amixer`.